# I get an specific day from relative date and also the last day of the relative date, how can I find the difference?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

```
$result = DB::table('customer')->where('isp',2)->get();
  // start_date is stored date in database
  $date= $result->start_date;
  $dts = Carbon::create($date);

  // in order to get the last day of relative month
  // get the last day of month for instance is equal to 2010-09-30 00:00:00

  // find the difference between in days
}
```

When I use from `diffindays` of Laravel the output is 0. Any ideas why?

Comment: `$result->start_date` should be throwing an error "Property start_date does not exist on this Collection instance". You need to be aware of what `$result` is; it's currently a `Collection`, which is a wrapper for an array, so `->start_date` won't return a single date unless you're looping over `$result`, or you fetch `$result` with `->first()` instead of `->get()`.

Comment: $result = DB::table('customer')->where('isp',2)->get()
start_date comes from database relation and its values is 2010-09-03 00:00:00
and also i have the got the last of this date which is equal to echo "the last is ". $last = 2010-09-30
when is use form diffinDays() the result is 0 and i do not know why?

Comment: I understand the question, but `$date = $result->start_date;` shouldn't work; `$result` is a `Collection`, and you can't access a property like that without looping...

Comment: Do you need diff in days from now? @karimjankarimi